# json-reformat-region on file open

Tags: json

currently I'm working a lot with json files. They tend to be a little bigger.
I'm a little fed up with always marking the whole file and then typing `M-x json-reformat-region`.

Is there a way to do this directly on opening the file?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this hook to achieve an effect like that:

`;; pretty print json files when they're opened
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("\\.json\\'" . (lambda ()
                                (javascript-mode)
                                (json-pretty-print (point-min) (point-max))
                                (goto-char (point-min))
                                (set-buffer-modified-p nil))))`

Comment: Hi I tried it but is not working. I even replaced `json-pretty-print` by `json-reformat-region`

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I don't get any errors, at least no obvious ones that I can see i the minibuffer. Is this for a different mode? I have `json-mode` and `json-snatcher` installed. I open the file and nothings happens...

Comment: In that case you might want to add a hook to `json-mode` that pretty prints the buffer.

Comment: So I finally was able to do this. The problem was that I didn't know to which mode the command `json-reformat-region` belongs. So here is my adapted version. `;; pretty print json files when they're opened
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist
             '("\\.json\\'" . (lambda ()
    (json-mode)
                                (json-reformat-region (point-min) (point-max))
    (goto-char (point-min))
                                (set-buffer-modified-p nil))))
`